# How to change the title of the backbaritem in uinavigationcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode

In my code, i have this line;

```
[self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem setTitle:@"back"];
```

but this doesn't change the title of the back button in uinavigationcontroller when the new controller is pushed.
So how to change the title of the back button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an easy 'hack' to solve this. Set the title of the parent view to whatever you want the back button to show and then push the controller. Don't forget to change the title back when you pop the view of the second controller.

```
self.title = @"back";
[self.navigationController push...];
```

Or create a new button:

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
[backButton release];
```

Comment: this hack shows that the underlying problem is that the back button title is set at a later stage. You'd better find a more suitable place to set the back button title, or assign your own back button at some point.